# Laravel 5.4 на мобильных устройствах не видно меню login / register

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, laravel

На сайте [isdon.ru](http://isdon.ru/) на мобильных устройствах не отображается меню `login/register`, а через компьютер отображается

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
            <title>Don IS: версия 2.0</title>
        
             <!-- JavaScripts -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
          
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
           
        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script> 
           
            <!--- Bootstrap and awesome fonts and icons -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
             
            <!-- Fonts -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">
        
            <!-- Styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
            {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
        
            <!-- Include Date Range Picker --> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" /> 
        
            
            <style>
                body {
                    font-family: 'Lato';
                }
        
                .fa-btn {
                    margin-right: 6px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body id="app-layout">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
        
                        <!-- Branding Image -->
                        <img src="{{ URL::asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="иконка" height="40px">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                        @if (!Auth::guest())
                          @if (count(Auth::user()->roles)) 
           @can('only_franchiser', Auth::user()) 
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Личный кабинет</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endcan
                                @can('only_manager', Auth::user()) 
                                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}">Панель администратора</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endcan
                                @can('only_delivery', Auth::user()) 
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/erp') }}">Склад</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endcan
                                @can('only_barista', Auth::user()) 
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk') }}">Касса</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/clients') }}">Новые клиенты</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/submitDelivery') }}">Доставка</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/submitEncashment') }}">Инкассация</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/erp/startERP') }}">Склад</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/allSells')}}">Продажи</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endcan
                                @can('only_partner', Auth::user())
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/partner') }}">Точки</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/partner/orders') }}">Заказы</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('/partner/materials') }}">Материалы</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endcan
                          @endif    
                        @endif
        
                        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @if (Auth::guest())
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Логин</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Зарегистрироваться</a></li>
                            @else
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
        
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        @if (count(Auth::user()->roles))
                                            @if ((Auth::user()->roles()->first()->role == "barista-1") || (Auth::user()->roles()->first()->role == "barista-2")) 
                                                 <li><a href="{{ url('/desk/StartOrFinish') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-key"></i>Открытие/закрытие смены</a></li>
                                            @endif
                                        @endif    
                                             <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        
            @yield('content')
        
            @yield('script')
         
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что у вас у этого меню проставлен класс `.collapse`, уберите его, или проставьте переключатель для разворачивающегося меню:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="app-navbar-collapse">Развернуть меню</a>
```